# Creating Children Objects with Parents Variables

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, parent

ok i've found alot of information close to an answer but nothing that really works and i really hope you guys can help.

imagine something like this

```
public class Parent
{
    public int A;
    int B;
    private int C;
    public Parent(int someIntA, int someIntB, int someIntC)
    {
        A = someIntA;
        B = someIntB;
        C = someIntC;
    }
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    public int D;
    // constructor
}
```

how can i create a constructor in such a way that when i create a object "Child" it has its own independent int A,B,C and D, Or do child objects not obtain its parents variable spots?

Comment: What do you mean by `independent`.  Do you mean that each `Child` instance has its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child object always contains all of the attributes of its parent. But your child won't be able to access the parent's `C` as it is `private` to the parent.
The `new` keyword is there to hide members. You should be able to use something like

```
private new C;
```

in your child class to hide the parent's member.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) for the description.

Answer (score 0):

One of the points of extending something is that you gain the variables they have.

If you just want them to have certain functions instead (and not 'share' variables), then you should consider either:

1. Set variables tp private so nobody else can access them
2. Use an interface instead

But it completely depends on what you want to do.

Comment: He asked not to use parent variables.

Comment: Oh, misunderstood. Ok, new answer.